# Symfony2 inheritance

Tags: inheritance, symfony

As we can use inheritance not only in entities but also in forms, I've designed the following structure:

Entities

- Class Person
- Class Professor extends Person
- Class Student extends Person

FormTypes

- Class PersonType
- Class ProfessorType extends PersonType
- Class StudentType extends PersonType

Now, my problem is in the controller. I don't know if I should use the person controller for all sub entities or if I should create a specific controller for each subclass.

Using a general controller helps a lot with the logic in common between entities and furthermore it wouldn't be necessary to add a whole controller each time a new subclass is created, but on the other hand, it is complicated to process specific data of each one. For instance, if I load a "person" and then I want to edit or show it I need to know what formtype and template correspond to it, but this is not possible at that level. I should use nested "if" to obtain the class of the person and so create the correct formtype and template (hardcode). This would not be "dynamic".

Maybe I could resolve it using different routes, but I would like to know what is the best (or at least a good) solution for this issue? Should I use inheritance in controllers too? How?

Answer (score 2):

We need to know [much] more about your application.

Anyway, it really depends on the controller's purpose. You can define a common ancestor controller, and then child controllers that extend the former, in whose you'll redefine methods you need.

Of course, you'll need specific routes for each action.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @moonwave99. So, with the structure I've described before, what would you do to show a person profile? Would you use an unique controller called "PersonController" with an action called "showAction" and there load this person and define the TWIG template regarding if it is a professor or a student? Or would you create two specific controllers (one for students and another for professors)? What about when I need to edit it? (using different form types)